# Can't pass parameters to std::thread?

Tags: multithreading, macos, c++11, clang, stdthread

I'm trying to use `std::thread`. My thread is supposed to call a method and pass a `struct` as a parameter, as so many examples show. Except my very simple code won't compile. For the record, I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340750/pass-multiple-arguments-into-stdthread) question but nothing there seems to help me.

Where I call the thread:

```
void Exporter::save() const {
    thread(write_to_disk, this->parameter).detach();
}
```

The signature of `write_to_disk`:

```
void write_to_disk(const Parameter& parameter)
```

`write_to_disk` is defined in a nameless namespace in the `.cpp` file.

I get the following error:

```
src/Exporter.cpp:65:5: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::thread'
    thread(write_to_disk, this->parameter).detach();
    ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:374:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f', but 2 arguments were provided
thread::thread(_Fp __f)
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:263:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
    thread(const thread&);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:270:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
    thread() _NOEXCEPT : __t_(0) {}
^
```

Comment: [Here's an MCVE that fits the description in the question and compiles and runs just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/272e2157f5f62ebf). Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't?

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82facb5aa54e073b) is the closest I can come to my code, but it runs perfectly. I also tried passing a simple int to `write_to_disk` and it fails with the same error. I wonder if it's a platform issue...

Comment: Also, not sure I trust this online compiler. There was a syntax error and it worked fine.

Comment: Which version of Xcode/clang are you using? A simple test on this end of something quite similar works fine for me.

Comment: Latest Xcode: 
`$ clang --version`
`Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)`
`Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0`
`Thread model: posix`

Comment: I've just pasted the content of the first MCVE Casey linked to into a .cpp file and called clang on it. I got the exact same constructor error.

Comment: Interesting - it works fine for me in CLion, which is using the same clang: Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: All I did was `clang test.cpp` - and boom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works fine for me if I do

```
clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

Comment: clang++ -std=c++11 fixed it. I suspect CMake is messing up my ninja files.