# Passing object by reference to std::thread in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pass-by-reference, stdthread

Why can't you pass an object by reference when creating a `std::thread` ?

For example the following snippit gives a compile error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

static void SimpleThread(int& a)  // compile error
//static void SimpleThread(int a)     // OK
{
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ":" << a << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 6;

    auto thread1 = std::thread(SimpleThread, a);

    thread1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:39:0,
                 from ./std_thread_refs.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(int))(int&)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(int&); _Args = {int&}]’
./std_thread_refs.cpp:19:47:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(int))(int&)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(int))(int&)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
```

I've changed to passing a pointer, but is there a better work around?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Explicitly initialize the thread with a [`reference_wrapper` by using `std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
auto thread1 = std::thread(SimpleThread, std::ref(a));
```

(or `std::cref` instead of `std::ref`, as appropriate). Per notes from [cppreference on `std:thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread):

> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g. with `std::ref` or `std::cref`).

Comment: The capture, sensibly, defaults to capture by value because otherwise things would fail horribly if the parameter went away before the thread could read it. You need to explicitly ask for this behavior so that there's something to indicate that you are assuming responsibility for ensuring that the target of the reference is still valid.

Comment: Excellent! I was hoping there was a way to explicitly pass a reference. C++11 to the rescue again :)

Answer (score 38):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078208/passing-object-by-reference-to-stdthread-in-c11#comment55909977_34078246), this answer elaborates on the reason why the arguments are not passed *by reference* to the thread function *by default*.

Consider the following function `SimpleThread()`:

```
void SimpleThread(int& i) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{1});
    i = 0;
}
```

Now, imagine what *would happen* if the following code compiled (it does **not** compile):

```
int main()
{
    {
        int a;
        std::thread th(SimpleThread, a);
        th.detach();
    }
    // "a" is out of scope
    // at this point the thread may be still running
    // ...
}
```

The argument `a` *would be passed* by reference to `SimpleThread()`. The thread may still be sleeping in the function `SimpleThread()` after the variable `a` has already gone out of scope and its lifetime has ended. If so, `i` in `SimpleThread()` would actually be a *dangling reference*, and the assignment `i = 0` would result in *undefined behaviour*.

By wrapping reference arguments with the class template `std::reference_wrapper` (using the function templates `std::ref` and `std::cref`) you explicitly express your intentions.

Comment: I think this is some kind of wrong argument on `why arguments are not passed by reference` because even using `std::ref(a)` leads to undefined behaviour in this scenario, isn't it ?

Comment: @ampawd Yes, using `std::ref(a)` still leads to *undefined behaviour*. However, explicitly typing `std::ref(a)` warns you against passing `a` by reference, whereas typing just `a` does not.

Comment: Having to write `std::ref(a)` (instead of just `a`) to pass `a` by reference prevents you from accidentally thinking that `a` is being passed by value.

Comment: Even if we use `std::ref`, there would be a dangling reference in the above example, so nothing changes, right? So, you mean, using `std::ref` is slightly better because it explicitly shows that it's using a reference?

Comment: @starriet: There are similar circumstances in which it would be safe to pass the reference (e.g. if the `thread` would be `join`-ed before the reference went out of scope, or the thread is being passed a reference to data with `static` storage duration). Using `std::ref` is *asserting* this is one of those situations. It's ensuring someone made a *choice* to use those semantics, rather than doing so by accident. It can't stop you from creating undefined behavior, but it can protect you from accidentally doing so.

Answer (score 11):

[`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) copy(/move) its arguments, you might even see the note:

> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g., with `std::ref` or `std::cref`).

So, you might use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) through [`std::ref`/`std::cref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
auto thread1 = std::thread(SimpleThread, std::ref(a));
```

or use lambda:

```
auto thread1 = std::thread([&a]() { SimpleThread(a); });
```

Answer (score 0):

don't pass by *reference* if your object is *stack based* allocated, pass by pointer to the new object created in the call of **thread API**. such object will live as long as thread but should be explicitly deleted before the thread termination.

example:

```
void main(){
...
std::string nodeName = "name_assigned_to_thread";
std::thread nodeThHandle = std::thread(threadNODE, new std::string(nodeName));
...
}

void threadNODE(std::string *nodeName){
/* use nodeName everywhere but don't forget to delete it before the end */
delete nodeName;
}
```

Comment: There's no benefit to passing by pointer here; if the pointer is allocated live as shown, then you may as well have just passed by value (it's not like anything else will share the pointer here, so no thread communication is possible). Either pass by value (when sharing not needed), by reference (when sharing needed and the value is guaranteed to outlive its use in the thread), or by `shared_ptr` (when you need to share and have no idea which thread will stop using it first). Passing by raw pointer with the thread assuming ownership may as well just be pass by value.