# Cpp: How to create a thread with method that requires pointer?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to create a thread that will automatically `join` after the work is done. So, I wrote the fallowing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    void work(atomic_bool & isWorking);

};

void Foo::work(atomic_bool & isWorking)
{
    //dosomestuff;
    int myVar = 0;
    while (myVar != 5)
    {
        myVar++;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    isWorking = true;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    std::atomic<bool> imdone;
    imdone = false;
    std::thread t1(&Foo::work, Foo(), imdone);

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Is Joinable: " << t1.joinable() << "\n";
        if (imdone)
        {
            imdone = false;
            t1.join();
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    cin.get();
}
```

I thought that I can pass argument like this: `std::thread t1(&Foo::work, Foo(), imdone);`, but not in case when the argument is a pointer. How am I supose to pass a pointer in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an object of the type whose member you want to call and pass ***its*** address like this:

```
Foo foo; // create an object
std::thread t1(&Foo::work, &foo, ...); // pass its address
```

In addition you are *passing a reference* so you need to use `std::ref` like this:

```
Foo foo; // create an object
std::thread t1(&Foo::work, &foo, std::ref(imdone)); // use std::ref()
```

Comment: It worked when I used `std::ref()`, but I dont understand why I have to use this function to make it work. What do I use it for, and when do I use it?

Comment: @Salin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078208/passing-object-by-reference-to-stdthread-in-c11/34078246 Basically to make sure that you really mean to capture by reference and that you understand that the reference must live longer than the thread.

Comment: @Salin You use it when the function you are calling expects a *reference*. It is needed because, when making a thread object, **all** parameters are **copied**. So you need to "hide" references within another object.