# Passing variable by reference on thread does not compile

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

I have started delving into Multi-threading and I am currently reading the C++ Concurrency in Action book.

On chapter 2 (Managing threads, p. 24), the author explains the usage of `std::ref` when passing in variables that are required to be passed in by reference.

He also explains that **not** using the `std::ref` to wrap your variable, the function on that thread will act upon the locally stored variable (due to the copy).

Naturally, I wanted to try both and I intentionally passed the argument without the `std::ref`...

However, the following code does not compile on either *clang, g++, vc++*. I also used both `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14` to make sure there is no language update that could have affected it.

```
void updatePos(double &pos_)
{
    pos_ = 12.5;
}

int main()
{
    double position = 0.0;

    std::thread pos_thread(updatePos,position); // does not compile

    pos_thread.join();

    std::cout<< "Position: " << position <<std::endl;
}
```

Online code example: https://rextester.com/IDQGG96391

The compiler error from clang is:

> /usr/include/c++/v1/thread:337:5: error: attempt to use a deleted
>   function
>       __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
>       ^ /usr/include/c++/v1/thread:347:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__thread_execute' requested here
>       __thread_execute(*__p, _Index());
>       ^ /usr/include/c++/v1/thread:359:42: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   'std::__1::__thread_proxy
>
> > ' requested here
> >         int __ec = pthread_create(&__t_, 0, &__thread_proxy<_Gp>, __p.get());
> >                                              ^ source_file.cpp:15:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
> >     'std::__1::thread::thread'
> >     requested here
> >         std::thread pos_thread(updatePos,position); // does not compile
> >                     ^ /usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:1069:5: note: '~__nat' has been explicitly marked deleted here
> >         ~__nat() = delete;

The book mentions that the way the `std::thread` constructor works, is similar to `std::bind`.

Has something changed in the language or am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: possibly duplicate of [Passing object by reference to std::thread in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078208/passing-object-by-reference-to-stdthread-in-c11)

Comment: is it possible that the example in the book without `std::ref` is about a `const&` ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: Nope... The example above does not have a `const`

Comment: @GauravDhiman: It's not possibly a duplicate. It IS a duplicate! I wonder why it didn't show up when I was searching for similar questions. Btw, the answer on that thread is not satisfactory. His answer just says that you should use `std::ref`. I know that already. I want to know why it doesn't compile.

Comment: not your example, the one in the book

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: Of course... lol. Sorry, I meant the example above in the book! My bad.!

Comment: i was asking because it does compile with the `const`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/tJLxQKpJdtTjR8Y6 otherwise you need `std::ref` afaik

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: How does that compile??? The function assigns a value to the variable passed by reference. Adding a `const` shouldn't allow that.

Comment: The second and subsequent parameters are copied by value. `double&` cannot bind to a value, but `const double&` can.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos please look at the link I posted. Of course I had to remove the assignment

Comment: The author of the book failed to have an exhaustive knowledge of C++ threading, and relied on the compiler (probably an earlier version of MSVC), where your code would compile.  The standard always mandated passing an rvalue to the thread function in your case; MSVC used to pass an lvalue.

Comment: a `double&` never makes a copy. If your code would work, then in which case would you need `std::ref` ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: In that case it compiles because of the `const`. The compiler can see that no changes will be allowed so it accepts it. But the book doesn't use a `const`.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos Yes, the book author made a mistake.  It was a mistake that probably compiled in MSVC at the time they wrote the book.  The fact it compiled in MSVC was also a mistake, this time by MSVC.  And as everyone knows, two wrongs always make a right.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Hmmm.... Harsh words. I hope you're wrong about the knowledge part. But I think you are correct about using an older compiler bit.

Comment: relying on no errors from a compiler to validate code is never good, so I am afraid also the knowledge part in Yakks comment is accurate

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos It sort of does; the c++11 standard does indeed say your code is illegal.  If I wanted to I could reopen your question and post that the code is illegal, and add my theory that the author was relying on MSVC which had a bug in std thread back when this book was first written, but that is colour commentary and not the answer.  :)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Yer... Fair enough. Nah, don't reopen it. It was a duplicate question. It's just that the answer was not explaining why it was working for the author.

Comment: Every book has errata, *Concurrency in Action* too, you can see it [here](https://www.cplusplusconcurrencyinaction.com/errata.html), where is a lot of fixes  on Pages 23/24. And I think, if you read it, you would never post this question.

Comment: @rafix07: Nope! I didn't know of this. I wouldn't have asked this question if I had seen this. I'm happy for the question to be erased. Thank you very much for sharing this link!