# How can I pass a std::atomic<int> variable to a function within a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I'm having trouble with a very basic program.

I want to do a monitoring function that can access two `int` who are constantly incremented in two other threads.

Here is my code and I compile with either `gcc -std=c++14 Monitoring.cpp  -pthread` or `gcc -std=c++11 Monitoring.cpp  -pthread`:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>


void monitor_function(std::atomic<int>& a1,std::atomic<int>& a2)
{
    while(1){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        std::cout<<"a1 = "<<a1<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"a2 = "<<a2<<std::endl;
    }
}

void thread_function_one(std::atomic<int>& a1)
{
    while (1){
        a1++;
    }
}

void thread_function_two(std::atomic<int>& a2)
{
    while (1){
        a2++;
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::atomic<int> a1(0);
    std::atomic<int> a2(0);
    std::thread t1(thread_function_one,a1);
    std::thread t2(thread_function_two,a2);
    std::thread t3(monitor_function,a1,a2);

    return 0;
}
```

Can you give me direction on how to use atomic variable inside threads ?

Thanks

---

**EDIT** :

I added protection and joined the threads :

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>


void monitor_function(std::atomic<int>& a1,std::atomic<int>& a2)
{
    while(1){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        std::cout<<"a1 = "<<a1<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"a2 = "<<a2<<std::endl;
    }
}

void thread_function_one(std::atomic<int>& a1)
{
    while (1){
        a1++;
        if (a1 > 1000000){
            a1 = -1000000;
        }
    }
}

void thread_function_two(std::atomic<int>& a2)
{
    while (1){
        a2++;
        if (a2 > 1000000){
            a2 = -1000000;
        } 
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::atomic<int> a1(0);
    std::atomic<int> a2(0);
    auto t1 = std::thread(thread_function_one,a1);
    auto t2 = std::thread(thread_function_two,a2);
    auto t3 = std::thread(monitor_function,a1,a2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Still got lot of compilation error, can launch my program

**EDIT 2** : added std::ref around a1 and a2  and it works, thanks.

```cpp
    auto t1 = std::thread(thread_function_one,std::ref(a1));
    auto t2 = std::thread(thread_function_two,std::ref(a2));
    auto t3 = std::thread(monitor_function,std::ref(a1),std::ref(a2));
```

Comment: whats wrong with your code? Is it not doing what you want it to do?

Comment: The problem I see will be the overflow of `int` with is UB.

Comment: related, maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078208/passing-object-by-reference-to-stdthread-in-c11

Comment: and you don't join the threads. There is a number of issues with the code. Which one specifically are you trying to fix?

Comment: Look at 3rd comment, use `std::ref`.

Comment: You've updated the code but still haven't accurately described the problem.  Please have a look at the duplicate proposed by @largest_prime_is_463035818 .

Comment: `std::thread(thread_function_one, std::ref(a1));` or `std::thread([&]() { thread_function_one(a1); });`.

Comment: Thanks, probleme was indeed not using std::ref