# How do I pass an atomic variable to a function to be modified through a lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, stdatomic

I am new to atomic variables. I am trying to modify [this](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/blob/master/host/examples/benchmark_rate.cpp)  C++ file to break out the `benchmark_rx_rate` function in its own file so I can use it in my project.

The main file has a bunch of std::atomic_ullong type variables for logging which I want to preserve. My ideal situation would be to define some struct of all the std::atomic_ullong I need in a `benchmark_rx_rate.h`, initialize it when I need it, and to pass through to my new benchmark_rx_rate function in a `benchmark_rx_rate.cpp` file.

On line 573 is where the function gets called, like so:

```
auto rx_thread = thread_group.create_thread([=, &burst_timer_elapsed]() {
                    benchmark_rx_rate(usrp,
                        rx_cpu,
                        rx_stream,
                        spb,
                        random_nsamps,
                        start_time,
                        burst_timer_elapsed,
                        elevate_priority,
                        rx_delay);
                });
```

I am starting small just trying to pass through the `num_overruns` variable which is a `std::atomic_ullong`. I have tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561981/how-can-i-pass-a-stdatomicint-variable-to-a-function-within-a-thread). I am now getting an error saying:

`use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<long unsigned int>::atomic(const std::atomic<long unsigned int>&)`

What is the best practice for providing am atomic variable to a function that will modify it, if the function is called through a lambda? How would the process differ from passing just a single atomic variable versus passing a struct of atomic variables?

Comment: Just capture `num_overruns` by reference like you do with `burst_timer_elapsed`?

Comment: The message says that you cannot copy an atomic variable, which you wouldn't want to anyway.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I didn't notice that was also atomic.. Thanks! I am also new to lambdas and didn't realize that you capture by reference like that.