# In std:async, error: reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I have a function that I would like to use it by parallel tasks. I got this error,

" error: reference to non-static member function must be called, auto future = std::async(this->process,hs,newset,newsetv);"

My code is given below.

In the function, I have these lines

```
auto future = std::async(std::launch::async,process,hs,newset,newsetv);
list<list<int> > tmp_list = future.get();
```

The prototype of the process function is given below,

```
list<list<int> > process(const list<int> &hs,const list<int> &newset,const vector<int> &newsetv)
```

These two functions are in the same class and public. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mre]

Comment: Once you fix the error using the duplicate, you will also need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078208/passing-object-by-reference-to-stdthread-in-c11/34078246