# Passing a class to a thread function

Tags: c++, multithreading

Hi i'm learning to use queue and i'm trying to make a simple read and write program. i have 2 thread 1 that sends the message got from std::cin and the other thread that waits for the queue to not be empty and prints the content when there's something in the queue. But when i execute my program the receiver receives nothing i think it's because they don't have the same object so i tried to give the reference to the object but it doesn't work i got this error message :

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/10/thread: In instantiation of ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(IPC&); _Args = {IPC*}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’:
main.cpp:35:44:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/10/thread:136:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  136 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "IPC.hpp"
#include <thread>

std::mutex mtx;

void thread_receiver(IPC ipc)
{
    std::string order;

    while (true) {
        if (ipc.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            order = ipc.getMsg(mtx);
            std::cout << "Order: " << order << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void thread_sender(IPC ipc)
{
    std::string order;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter order : ";
        std::cin >> order;
        ipc.sendMsg(mtx, order);
    }
}

int main()
{
    IPC ipc;
    std::thread thread1(thread_sender, ipc);
    std::thread thread2(thread_receiver, ipc);
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
//IPC.hpp
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>

class IPC {
    public:
        IPC();
        ~IPC();
        std::string getMsg(std::mutex &m);
        void sendMsg(std::mutex &m, std::string msg);
        int getQueueSize();
        bool isEmpty();

    private:
        std::queue<std::string> _order_q;
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078208/passing-object-by-reference-to-stdthread-in-c11, use `std::ref` if IPC is passed by reference.

Comment: Opinion: The `IPC` class should probably own the mutex. The current implementation allows for locking the same queue with different `mutex` instances.